# How to perform a JButton's action listener a certain number of times

Tags: java, arrays, swing, random, actionlistener

I have some code where I have code with 5 JButtons and I have a seperate array that generates a random number between 1-6 (dice roll) and inside the action listener I have just the part that adds my button to my panel (panel.add(roll1)) and before the action listener I have an array which generates the random number and then I have a switch saying if the random number is 1 then set an image to dice1 if array is 2 set image to dice2. So I have all this working now since I'm making the game of yahtzee I need to know how to make this runnable at a max of 3 times per move.  Right now the JButton is only clicked once and it outputs other JButtons with random dice images, but when I click the roll button button again the dice does not roll it stays the same.  How would you do this?

```
public static void randomRoll(final JPanel panel) throws Exception
  {

    final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Dice-1.png/45px-Dice-1.png"));
    final ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/Dice-2.png/45px-Dice-2.png"));
    final ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Dice-3.png/45px-Dice-3.png"));
    final ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Dice-4.png/45px-Dice-4.png"));
    final ImageIcon icon4 = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Dice-5.png/45px-Dice-5.png"));
    final ImageIcon icon5 = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Dice-6.png/45px-Dice-6.png"));

    final ImageIcon [] diceIcons = {icon, icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4, icon5};

    int array [] = new int [5];


    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      array [i]= (int) (Math.random () * 6) + 1;
      System.out.println(array[i]);
    }

    final JButton roll1 = new JButton(diceIcons[array[0]-1]);
    final JButton roll2 = new JButton(diceIcons[array[1]-1]);
    final JButton roll3 = new JButton(diceIcons[array[2]-1]);
    final JButton roll4 = new JButton(diceIcons[array[3]-1]);
    final JButton roll5 = new JButton(diceIcons[array[4]-1]);
    final JButton dice = new JButton ("Roll Dice");

    dice.setBounds(40, 40, 100, 30);
    panel.add(dice);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    dice.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        roll1.setBounds(40, 100, 70, 70);
        roll2.setBounds(40, 180, 70, 70);
        roll3.setBounds(40, 260, 70, 70);
        roll4.setBounds(40, 340, 70, 70);
        roll5.setBounds(40, 420, 70, 70);

        //Adding to JFrame
        panel.add(roll1);
        panel.add(roll2);
        panel.add(roll3);
        panel.add(roll4);
        panel.add(roll5);
        panel.doLayout();
        panel.repaint();
        panel.revalidate();
     }
    });


  }
```

Update

```
dice.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    int array [] = new int [5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      array [i]= (int) (Math.random () * 6) + 1;
      System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
final JButton roll1 = new JButton(diceIcons[array[0]-1]);
final JButton roll2 = new JButton(diceIcons[array[1]-1]);
final JButton roll3 = new JButton(diceIcons[array[2]-1]);
final JButton roll4 = new JButton(diceIcons[array[3]-1]);
final JButton roll5 = new JButton(diceIcons[array[4]-1]);


    roll1.setBounds(40, 100, 70, 70);
    roll2.setBounds(40, 180, 70, 70);
    roll3.setBounds(40, 260, 70, 70);
    roll4.setBounds(40, 340, 70, 70);
    roll5.setBounds(40, 420, 70, 70);

    //Adding to JFrame
    panel.add(roll1);
    panel.add(roll2);
    panel.add(roll3);
    panel.add(roll4);
    panel.add(roll5);
    panel.doLayout();
    panel.repaint();
    panel.revalidate();
 }
});
```

Comment: May you show us some code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Could you help now? I just want the JButton to be able to be clicked at a max of 3 times and do the same thing of having it generate another 5 random dice

Answer (score 1):

You can set each JButton an actionCommand using `setActionCommand("add" + "1");` //say that '1' is your 'i' value from the for loop

Then, in the implemented method from ActionListiner:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String cmd = e.getActionCommand();

    if (cmd.equals("add1")){
        System.out.println("from add1");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your randomization code,

```
int array [] = new int [5];


for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  array [i]= (int) (Math.random () * 6) + 1;
  System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

is called within your `randomRoll(...)` method, but is **not** called within the JButton's ActionListener. If you want the button press to do randomization, then the randomization code **must** be within the listener that is tripped when you press the button.

Other issues that are unrelated to your problem:

- Avoid null layouts and `setBounds(...)` as that will cause endless frustration with bad looking GUI's that are a bear to debug or enhance. Instead use layouts, here a GridLayout would work fine to hold your dice images.
- You may be better off displaying your dice in JLabels rather than in JButtons, unless you absolutely need to make them "pressable".
- You will want to read the images into your ImageIcons once on program start up, and store the values in a field.
- Your `randomRoll(...)` method is static which suggests that your program itself is possibly over-using static modifier

---

Note, to limit the number of button presses to 3, place a counter inside of your button's ActionListener, and then either disable the button when the count reaches 3, or else exit the action listener when the count is greater than 3. For example in my code, I've got something like:

```
private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
  private Random random = new Random();
  private int buttonPressCount = 0;

  public ButtonAction(String name) {
     super(name);
     int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
     putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     // check if number of presses exceeds max
     if (buttonPressCount >= BUTTON_PRESS_TOTAL_COUNT) {
        return; // we've exceeded our max
     }
     for (JLabel jLabel : dieLabels) {
        int index = random.nextInt(dieImageList.size());
        jLabel.setIcon(dieImageList.get(index));
     }

     buttonPressCount++;

     // or do this -- disable the button
     if (buttonPressCount >= BUTTON_PRESS_TOTAL_COUNT) {
        setEnabled(false);
     }
  }
}
```

---

Example that uses JLabels and layout managers:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DiceRoller extends JPanel {
   private static final String BASE_PATH = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/";
   private static final String[] DICE_PATH = {
      "c/c5/Dice-1.png/45px-Dice-1.png",
      "1/18/Dice-2.png/45px-Dice-2.png",
      "7/70/Dice-3.png/45px-Dice-3.png",
      "a/a9/Dice-4.png/45px-Dice-4.png",
      "6/6c/Dice-5.png/45px-Dice-5.png",
      "5/5c/Dice-6.png/45px-Dice-6.png"
 };
   private static final int BUTTON_PRESS_TOTAL_COUNT = 3;
   private static final int BUTTON_COUNT = 5;

   private List<Icon> dieImageList = new ArrayList<>();
   private Icon emptyIcon;
   private JLabel[] dieLabels = new JLabel[BUTTON_COUNT];

   public DiceRoller() throws IOException {
      for (String dicePath : DICE_PATH) {
         String path = BASE_PATH + dicePath;
         URL url = new URL(path);
         BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
         dieImageList.add(new ImageIcon(img));
      }

      int biWidth = dieImageList.get(0).getIconWidth();
      int biHeight = dieImageList.get(0).getIconHeight();
      BufferedImage emptyImage = new BufferedImage(biWidth, biHeight,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      emptyIcon = new ImageIcon(emptyImage);

      int gap = 8;
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, gap));
      btnPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
      for (int i = 0; i < dieLabels.length; i++) {
         dieLabels[i] = new JLabel(emptyIcon);
         btnPanel.add(dieLabels[i]);
      }

      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.add(new JButton(new ButtonAction("Roll")));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      private Random random = new Random();
      private int buttonPressCount = 0;

      public ButtonAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (buttonPressCount >= BUTTON_PRESS_TOTAL_COUNT) {
            return; // we've exceeded our max
         }
         for (JLabel jLabel : dieLabels) {
            int index = random.nextInt(dieImageList.size());
            jLabel.setIcon(dieImageList.get(index));
         }

         buttonPressCount++;

         if (buttonPressCount >= BUTTON_PRESS_TOTAL_COUNT) {
            setEnabled(false);
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      DiceRoller roller = null;
      try {
         roller = new DiceRoller();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Roll");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(roller);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: But it works once with this current code.  Are you saying I would have to do that if I want to perform the randomization more than once?

Comment: @Lebron: it works once because **it is only called once**, when this method is called, and that doesn't make sense for your purposes. You want randomization to occur each time the button is pressed, and so the randomization **must** go into the listener code.

Comment: I did what you said it is performing the randomization code, but its not putting it on the jbutton, I have a system.out.println with the array and it will show the numbers every time is clicked but the jbuttons arent changing. Ill add an update

Comment: @Lebron: you need to add the buttons before you do any rolling and add each button only once, not with each roll. In the roll ActionListener all you do is set the Icons of the buttons that are already in place, and again, avoid null layouts. Also, when posting code, try to post code that is short but that compiles and runs for us. For example, please see my example code above. It uses JLabels, but JButtons would work the same.